# Adding lists as a value to a dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wanna create a dict with values of  a list .
here is my code:

```
vo = [6, 5, 4, 4, 1, 0, -2, -2, -2, -2]  
out1 = {}  
A = []  
A.append(vo[0])  
out1[1] = A  
s = 1  
for i in range(1 , len(vo)):

    if  vo[i] == vo[i-1]:
    
        A.append(vo[i])
        out1[s] = A
    
    
                
   else:
    
       s += len(A)
       A.clear()
       A.append(vo[i])
       out1[s] = A
```

and here it's results :

```
{1: [-2, -2, -2, -2], 2: [-2, -2, -2, -2], 3: [-2, -2, -2, -2], 5: [-2, -2, -2, -2], 6: [-2, -2, -2, -2], 7: [-2, -2, -2, -2]}
```

but I want this :

```
{ 1 : [6] , 2:[5] , 3 : [4 , 4 ] , 5: [1] , 6: [0] , 7 : [-2 , -2 , -2 , -2 ] }
```

how can I fix my probelm?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain the logic how do you get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `A` is a list (mutable, pointer), and therefore when you assign a dictionary element to `A` and subsequently `.clear()` and change `A`, it changes previously assigned dictionary elements that point to `A`. If you change the lines

```
out1[s] = A
```

to

```
out1[s]=A.copy()
```

it should fix the problem. This would include the initial assignment too:

```
out1[1]=A.copy()
```

A simple example is if you do the following in sequence

```
A=[1]
out={1:A}
A.append(2)
print(out)
```

You will get

```
{1:[1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you skipped the 4 in your dictionary but you can do it like this:

```
vo = [6, 5, 4, 4, 1, 0, -2, -2, -2, -2]  
out1 = {}

s = 1
out1[s] = [vo[0]]
for i in range(1, len(vo)):
    if vo[i] == vo[i-1]:
        out1[s].append(vo[i])
    else:
        s += len(out1[s])
        out1[s] = [vo[i]]

print(out1)
```

Output :
`{1: [6], 2: [5], 3: [4, 4], 5: [1], 6: [0], 7: [-2, -2, -2, -2]}`